# Can't install PyAudio on windows 10, python 3.9.5

Tags: python, windows, pyaudio, python-3.9, amd-processor

Trying to download PyAudio by `pip install PyAudio` but this isn't working. I'm using Python 3.9.5
I also tried `python -m pip install pyaudio` but it didn't work. Anyone having the same error?

See the code below for reference ↓

```
    Collecting PyAudio
      Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
      Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\keepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u
-c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';f
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\keepa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-trp3euxd'
           cwd: C:\Users\keepa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e979x4nc\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\
      Complete output (9 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
      Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
    Failed to build PyAudio
    Installing collected packages: PyAudio
        Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\keepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u
-c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';f
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\keepa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-isa75oeg\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\keepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio'
             cwd: C:\Users\keepa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e979x4nc\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\
        Complete output (9 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
        running build_ext
        building '_portaudio' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\keepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u
-c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\keepa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e979x4nc\\pyaudio_403fcffb6b004552a1d48ac0e0876dd8\\setup.py'"'"';f
= getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\keepa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-isa75oeg\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\keepa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The error seems to be saying youy need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater, try downloading that (instructions in error) and see how you go :)

`Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Answer (score 0):

When running python 3.6 this works, but with python 3.7 it doesn't.

PyAudio only supports up to python 3.6:

```
pip will fetch and install PyAudio wheels (prepackaged binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.
```

The workarounds would be to use a supported version of python, or to build and install manually - if the latter, you'll need to make sure you have the correct libraries installed and configured.

I should point out that PyAudio appears to be deprecated. It hasn't received an update since March 2017. Therefore I recommend you find another package for this.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem due to the absence of Microsoft compiler that i didn't want to install on my PC.
I used this website unofficial pre-compiled pyaudio wheel packages, it worked well. So download wheel files at this site:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
Of course, download the wheel version that is compatible with your python version.

use the command:
pip install *wheel_file_downloaded*

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pipwin
python -m pipwin install pyaudio
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).